# Use consumerProguardFiles in my AAR library and get file not found while using obfuscationdictionary

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

In my library i use `consumerProguardFiles` in *release* build type. My proguard role is :

```
-obfuscationdictionary proguard-dictionary.txt
-classobfuscationdictionary proguard-dictionary.txt
-packageobfuscationdictionary proguard-dictionary.txt

-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/removal/writeonly,!field/marking/private,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable
-flattenpackagehierarchy
-allowaccessmodification
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature,MethodParameters,LocalVariableTable,LocalVariableTypeTable
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses
```

When developers use my library (AAR) in the project and getting release build and use `minifyEnabled true`, get `proguard-dictionary.txt` is not found:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"File not found: /Users/USER/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/12e928515abf78e8a4387fd92c3a399b/proguard-dictionary.txt","sources":[{"file":"/Users/USER
 /.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/12e928515abf78e8a4387fd92c3a399b/proguard-dictionary.txt"}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"File not found: /Users/USER
 /.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/12e928515abf78e8a4387fd92c3a399b/proguard-dictionary.txt","sources":[{"file":"/Users/USER
 /.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/12e928515abf78e8a4387fd92c3a399b/proguard-dictionary.txt"}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"File not found: /Users/USER
 /.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/12e928515abf78e8a4387fd92c3a399b/proguard-dictionary.txt","sources":[{"file":"/Users/USER
 /.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/12e928515abf78e8a4387fd92c3a399b/proguard-dictionary.txt"}],"tool":"D8"}
```

How can I use `-obfuscationdictionary` without using a dictionary file?
or
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            // automatically add your proguard rules into your library user
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules-dic.pro', 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>

Answer (score 3):

All the rules mentioned should *never* go into a file pointed to by `consumerProguardFiles`, they look line rules which should go into the `proguardFiles` for building the library. Also, Unless you have very special requirements, leaving out all of `-obfuscationdictionary`, `-classobfuscationdictionary` and `-packageobfuscationdictionary` from `proguardFiles` for building the library will be the best thing to to.

The `consumerProguardFiles` is used for rules which the consumer of the library need to have for the library to work. All these rules will go into the build for the project consuming the library. If you library does not use reflection, then `consumerProguardFiles` will most likely not be needed at all.

Comment: One of my customers has a problem to build their project and i understand one of the libraries has sample proguard class name and method and getting an exception for the duplicate class name. by adding `-obfuscationdictionary` to proguard it fixed but when add `minifyEnabled true` for release version get error dictionary file not found.. FYI: I use **reflection** in my library.

Comment: If two libraries have duplicate names, then one of the libraries have to change names, and that can only be solved by one of the library providers. See https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#library for minifying a librayr. If your library use reflection, then what need to go into `consumerProguardFiles` are the keep rules for you library to ensure that the reflection the library use will still work. Also see https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library for more information on building `aar`s.

Answer (score 1):

Post some addtional tips on Dharman's answer for those are confused on it.
The rules for proguard dic "-classobfuscationdictionary dic.txt" only add in 'proguard-rules-dic.pro', so it with not be add into lib proguard-rules file.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            // automatically add your proguard rules into your library user
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // the rules for proguard dic "-classobfuscationdictionary dic.txt" only add in 'proguard-rules-dic.pro', so it with not be add into lib proguard-rules file
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules-dic.pro', 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem a few days ago, this caused by your aar file which not include the "proguard-dictionary.txt" file, you can check by decompressing your aar file. To solve this problem, you can do like this:

- create a folder named "assets" under your library, then put your "proguard-dictionary.txt" file to this folder.
- add the "assets" folder as android assets source, you can add the below code to your build.gradle file:

  ```
   sourceSets {
       main {
           res.srcDirs = [
                   'src/main/res'
           ]

           java.srcDirs = [
                   'src/main/java'
           ]
           assets.srcDirs = [
                   'assets',
                   'src/main/assets'
           ]
      }}
  ```

And the file tree may like this:

```
 │  build.gradle
 │  proguard-rules.pro
 │
 ├─assets
 │      proguard-dictionary.txt
```

Anyway, if you can read Chinese, you can refer to this [blog](https://blog.csdn.net/zhuzp_blog/article/details/115356721?spm=1001.2014.3001.5501)

Comment: It's not the right way to do it.  Add the dictionary file next to *proguard-rules* and follow the Gradle code:
```groovy

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules-dic.pro', 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

```